# Given the pointer, deleting an element from a LinkedList collection

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) of objects, and a pointer to an object of the `LinkedList` which I want to delete.

There is a method [`remove(object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)), which can be used to do delete an object, but as the documentation describes, it checks for all the elements one by one, and chooses the one object, which is the same semantically.

But this method doesn't fit my requirements.

Since I have a pointer to the object I want to delete, I should be able to delete it in `O(1)` time, since the `LinkedList` is a doubly linked list. **Is there any other way to do so without implementing my own `LinkedList` class?**

Comment: "Pointers" in Java are called "references".

Comment: @dasblinkenlight although I agree, Java doesn't seem to help that argument as there is even an exception called "NullPointerException". "NullReferenceException" would of been better ;-).

Comment: can you show us your code please?

Comment: If you are using Java 8+ you can use `linkedList.removeIf(e-> some_condition);`

Comment: @YCF_L with that solution, it will remove all of the elements of the collection that satisfy the given predicate. not just the first as the aforementioned `remove` method does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot delete an object from a `LinkedList` in O(1) if all you have is a reference to the object itself.

You can delete an object if you keep a `ListIterator<E>` object positioned at the item that you would like to remove by calling [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove()) on the iterator, but it does not help much, because your iterator would get invalidated the moment the list is modified.

Here is an example of how to keep the removal O(1). Search remains O(n), though:

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add("hello");
list.add("world");
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
ListIterator<String> iter = list.listIterator();
String s;
while ((s = iter.next()) != null && !s.equals("world"))
    ;
// When it is time to delete
iter.remove();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
```

Because of the `ConcurrentModificationException`, writing your own implementation of `LinkedList<E>` and keeping a reference to the node for future deletion remains your best option with pure linked lists.

Your other option is using `LinkedHashSet<E>`, which offers predictable enumeration order and O(1) deletions in exchange for using more memory.

Comment: Gives a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: @Mooncrater You are right, I forgot about the pesky concurrent modification exception, which is not even mentioned in the docs for `remove()` of `ListIterator`. Thanks for pointing this out. I guess your best option is to implement your own linked list, and store list node for future deletion.

Comment: @Mooncrater Also consider using `LinkedHashSet<E>` if it is applicable in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
public void remove(Car searchedFor) {
  for (Iterator<Car> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Car c = it.next;
      if (c == searchedFor) {
        it.remove();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's not an O(1) complexity

Comment: Also, note that the aforementioned overload of the `remove` method from the List API only removes **the first occurrence** of the specified element from this list, if it is present.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution to my problem was using both `List` and `HashSet` together. Since we're using a `HashSet` we can't work with duplicates.

**Insertion:** Insert in both `List` and `HashSet`. `O(1)` time.
**Deletion:** Delete from `HashSet`, if exists. `O(1)` time.
**Traversal:** Traverse the `List`. Access only if the `HashSet` contains that object.

Note that I'm not trying to replicate the working of a `LinkedList` here. I'm just sharing what worked for me.